# How to make a http request before switching the Tab's using TabBarView

Tags: flutter, tabbar

I have the same http request just using different property

If I make them separate widgets the screen will just be blank until I switch to the Tab.

I want to make it pre-load, so even before I switch to other Tab.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how it's done, because every time you press the tab it will make a new http request, what you should do is to use some state management solution (eg. BLoC) to manage your app, on creation of the route containing the tabs you just make one request to load both responses, this will make the performance of your app much better.

I recommend this tutorial to learn BLoC:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQMfaQeCL6M&t=726s

After that you will automatically know what you need to make it work.